# Reading file passed in cmd

Tags: java, cmd

i have problem which is probably easy but in can't figure it out. I'm writing simple java program called task1 to read a file and calculate some values. I run this program in cmd like this:

> cmd: java task1 calculate

Word "calculate" after "task1" is an argument which start my method to calculate some values. But i would like to calculate some values in a file called values.txt. My problem is that i don't know how to write my code to that read file. This file is passed as argument in cmd like that:

> cmd: java task1 calculate < values.txt

hope, you can understand my problem. It Would be awesome if you can just tell me how to print this values in my file

```
        if(args.length == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Insert some arguments");
        }
        else if(args[0].equals("calculate"))
        {
            //here i would like to read my file (values.txt) 
        }
```

I appreciate your help and i am sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Files#readAllLines()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29). This will read a text file and store every line in
a List collection:

```
//Path valuesPath = Paths.get("VALUES_DIR", "values.txt");
Path valuesPath = Paths.get("./" + args[0]);

try {
  List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(valuesPath, Charset.defaultCharset()));

  for (String line : lines) {     //print lines (or do whatever you need)
    System.out.println(line);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where `args[0]` is the name of the file to read (on the same directory where the task1.jar is).

Call your java program as:

```
java -jar task1.jar values.txt
```

**EDIT:**

To read piped file as standard in:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  //print lines (or do whatever you need)
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

call your task as:

```
java task1 calculate < VALUES_PATH\values.txt
```

Where VALUES_PATH is the complete path where your file is.

**Note** that when you use `<` then you can't get back the command line in your own program.

Comment: I get error: The system cannot find the file specified. I had my vales.txt file in same directory as my task1.java file. So i assume that this is not a problem or is it?

Comment: In the code example, `VALUES_DIR` is the directory where the values.txt file is. Also you can call `Paths.get()` with only one argument with the complete path to values.txt. You dont need to use `<` here to read the file, you only need to pass the path of the file to your program.

Comment: Yes i need to use `<` because there will be more files in this same directory.
How do i call  `Paths.get()` ?

Comment: I see but i get this one Error: Unable to access jarfile. Sorry but i'm new in this stuff so i don't get it right away. But still i can't call java program as you present but i have to read it as i posted in my question.

Comment: I finally get it, thanks! The second solution helped.

Answer (score 2):

You should use buffered reader for that.
When you do

```
cmd: java task1 calculate < values.txt
```

you pass the contents of values.txt in the program as standard input.

The code would look like this

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

This way you read a line with BufferedReader.

For more please consult http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-bufferedreader-readline-string-examples

PS: It is also possible to directly read a file from disk, no need to pipe it to the program.

You do that like this:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

Comment: Ok, i will user the first one, because that is what i need. But i get error: The system cannot find the file specified. My file is in the same directory as my program task1.java

Comment: This error should happen with the second method. Can you paste the whole error?

Comment: @Rok do you get this error from java or from the os?

Comment: When i run this in cmd is this error (The system cannot find the file specified.) the only thing i get. I don't understand why it cannot find this file

Comment: As JosEdu said, you should try to read them directly. You can specify the files with arguments. Also JosEdu solution is more suitable for this.

Comment: How to do you mean not read the file from disk? I have my file and my task1.java in `C:\Users\Rok\Desktop\task`.